# Facing some issues in multi level category hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I want to simply create a multilevel (three level deep) category hierarchy by using adjacency list model.

Category table:

```
________________________________________________________________________
| id              |  parent_id     | name            | page_order
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
| 1               |  0             | Home            |     0
| 2               |  0             | sweets          |     0
| 3               |  2             | tin sweet       |     0
| 4               |  3             | tin rasugulla   |     0
| 5               |  2             | kaju katri      |     0
| 6               |  2             | ras malai       |     0
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

My result should be like that (according to above table):

- home
- sweets

  - tin sweet

    - tin rasugulla
  - kaju katri
  - ras malai

But i am getting little different output:

- home
- sweets

  - tin sweet
  - kaju katri
  - ras malai
  - tin rasugulla

here is my codeigniter code:

```
    public function get_nested(){
             // fetching categories from table
             $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    $pages = $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->result_array();

    // now creating category tree
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        if ($page['parent_id'] == 0){
             $array[$page['id']] = $page;
        }else {
            $array[$page['parent_id']]['children'][$page['id']] = $page;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

snap shot of query result: `var_dump($pages);`

[image]

snap shot of `var_dump($array)`:

[image]

here's a code to create a list for output:

```
function toUL($array)
{
    $html = '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        $html .= '<li>' . $value['title'];

        // do we have any children?
        if (isset($value['children']) && count($value['children'])){
            $html .= toUL($value['children']);
        }
        $html .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $html .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

    return $html;
}
```

my above code giving me notice error:  undefined index: title

Comment: can you post result of the query `$pages` array

Comment: get_nested function does not produces the array you wanted and it will produce 2 layer array.

Comment: ok.. i am posting snap shot of var_dump($array)

Comment: look i posted a query result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your nesting code is referencing nonexistent IDs in $array.

For "tin rasugulla", parent_id = 3, which doesn't exist on the root level of $array so it gets created, when it should in fact try to find the parent with ID 3, which is below "sweets".

This should work:

```
public function get_nested(){
    // fetching categories from table
    $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
    $pages = $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->result_array();

    // now creating category tree
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        if ($page['parent_id'] == 0){
            $array[$page['id']] = $page;
        } elseif (isset($array[$page['parent_id']])) {
            $array[$page['parent_id']]['children'][$page['id']] = $page;
        } else {
            foreach ($array as $root_id => $parent) {
                if (isset($parent['children'][$page['parent_id']])) {
                    $array[$root_id]['children'][$page['parent_id']]['children'][$page['id']] = $page;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Great! I've edited my post to include your suggestions as I don't have enough karma to accept them directly.